# Excel IF rules. Can I enter the value of a live cell if the cell applied to the formula passes the test?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IF(R5=M5,"B5","0")
```

The above is what I am working with.  If the answer is no, the '0' works as I intend it to.  If the cell passes the test, I want it to draw the response from cell B5.  When I apply the formula, the entry is displayed as B5, which I guess is what I am asking of the equation.

How do I get the B5 to be recognised as the value of a cell?

Comment: Remove the quotes around B5 use `=IF(R5=M5,B5,"0")`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotation marks.
It should be:

```
 =IF(R5=M5,B5,0)
```

Quotation marks are used to indicated text, not values, or cell references.